# 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the bt.Backtest(bt_strategy, price_data)

For price_data I am trying to use a Data Frame of my own, extracted from a broker (Oanda) in order to test on batches of timeframes and instruments I want.

The only thing is after edits of the Dataframe in order to make it similar to the bt.get option my price_data which stores the Dataframe doesn't work and gives me the following error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

```
#I changed the index format to make my strategy with BT work
EURUSD_df.index=pd.to_datetime(EURUSD_df.index, format = '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
EURUSD_df.tail()

close   high    low open
2018-12-27  1.14448 1.14728 1.14271 1.14296
2018-12-30  1.14649 1.14696 1.14216 1.14372
2019-01-01  1.13447 1.14970 1.13250 1.14649
2019-01-02  1.13942 1.14112 1.13077 1.13431
2019-01-03  1.13951 1.14191 1.13457 1.13930

import talib

!pip install bt
import bt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

EMA_short=talib.EMA(EURUSD_df['close'],timeperiod=10).to_frame()
EMA_long=talib.EMA(EURUSD_df['close'],timeperiod=40).to_frame()

signal=EMA_long.copy()
signal[EMA_long.isnull()]=0
signal[EMA_short>EMA_long]=1
signal[EMA_short<EMA_long]=-1
combined_df=bt.merge(signal,EURUSD_df["close"],EMA_short,EMA_long)
combined_df.columns=["Signal","Price","EMA_short","EMA_long"]
combined_df.plot(secondary_y=["Signal"])

print(EURUSD_df[['close']])
#EURUSD_df=EURUSD_df['close'].reset_index
#print(EURUSD_df['close'])
price_data=EURUSD_df['close']
price_data=price_data.append(pd.Series(name='NameOfNewRow'))
print(price_data)

bt_strategy = bt.Strategy('EMA_crossover',
                          [bt.algos.WeighTarget(signal),
                          bt.algos.Rebalance()])
bt_backtest = bt.Backtest(bt_strategy,price_data)
bt_result = bt.run(bt_backtest)
bt_result.plot(title='Backtest result')
```

Can someone help/guide me, please?

Much appreciated!

Ciprian

Comment: Please post the full backtrace when you ask questions about debugging an error

Comment: `price_data=EURUSD_df['close']` returns a series, not a dataframe, e.g. one column. So one column doesn't have a `.columns` attribute. What are you expecting the output of that line to be?

Comment: As the message suggests, .columns is not an attribute of a pandas Series. It is an attribute of a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you.  I wanted to get a Dataframe with only one column and the index. The column will be the closing price only. My new error is "AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'columns' " Apologies, I am quite a newbie :) @G.Anderson

Comment: If you need it to be in a dataframe, all you have to do is wrap it in a dataframe constructor. Then you can use the `.columns` attribute. So `EURUSD_df['close']`->`pd.DataFrame(EURUSD_df['close'])` et voila